# How to build 2nd rank tensors from set of vectors?

Tags: tensor-products, tensors, tensor-decomposition

Suppose we have 3 vectors: $A_i$, $B_i$, $C_i$, where $i=1,2,3$. How to build all possible dependent 2nd rank tensors based on these vectors?

I believe, that at first we need to obtain all possible products like $A_iB_j$, $B_iC_j$, $A_iC_j$, $C_iC_j$, etc. Then tensor should be something like $T_{ij} = C_1A_iB_j+C_2B_iC_j+...$. Is that correct? Should all the product be linear independent? How to check linear independency? It seems, total amount of products should not be more than $3X3$, should it?

Answer (score 1):

If $A,B,C$ are rank one tensors then
$$A\otimes A\ ,\ B\otimes B\ ,\ C\otimes C$$
are rank two tensor tensors as well
$$A\otimes B\ ,\ A\otimes C\ ,\ B\otimes A\ ,\ B\otimes C\ ,\ C\otimes A\ ,\ C\otimes B,$$
to begin, but also linear combination of them.

Comment: your $T$ will look like as $$T=cc_1A\otimes B+cc_2B\otimes C+cc_3 C\otimes A+\cdots,$$ where the $cc_s$ are scalars

Comment: for completeness there are 9 coefficients $$T=cc_1 A\otimes A +cc2B\otimes B +cc_3C\otimes C+cc_4A\otimes B+cc_5A\otimes C+cc_6B\otimes A+cc_7 B\otimes C+cc_8 C\otimes A+cc_9 C\otimes B$$